# Android Grid Layout

Tags: java, android, android-gridlayout

I'm working on an Android app but I have problem with the GUI (The GridLayout).

I wonder if it is possible to choose which column, a view will be included, because I have to fill the first two column in a loop and fill the others afterwards.

Comment: Try here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Comment: I would like to use Grid Layout

Comment: Maybe this examples can help you: http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/669 http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_the_Android_GridLayout_in_XML_Layout_Resources

Comment: For now I added the views one after the other

Answer (score 0):

*The example above is a gridView with some pictures **(mThumbIds)** that are shown.*

*Create a gridView via xml.*

Then get it in your code like this:

```
GridView gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
```

*Then create a **image Adapter** , and set attach it to your **GridView** :*

```
imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
gv.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
```

Here the code for your ImageAdapter:

The **getView method** is executed for each item in your grid.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
    };
}
```